# I am facing issue with infragistic ultrawingrid

Tags: c#, ultrawingrid

Am having main and sub forms in a single form. But Sub form contains grid with scrollbar(Vertical) and main form also contains scrollbar(Vertical).
My issue here is, when i click on sub form grid and clicking on outside the sub form(main form).
Here main form scrollbar not working when i click on outside sub form(main form), sub form scrollbar only working even i clicked in main form.

what my Expectation is ?
When i click on main form,scrollbar should be worked and also when i click on sub form grid only sub form scrollbar should worked.

Please any one help me out.

When i click on main form,scrollbar should be worked and also when i click on sub form grid only sub form scrollbar should worked.